# Need to shorten get function

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the last line in this code -  I know it is getting the equivalent plaintext charcter in `encdic` (encyption dictionary and join it all together to create an encrypt message. what is the `l.lower` code doing (taking upper characters and converting it to lower? If all characters are already lower case - how do i shorten the last line

```
return s.join(encdic.get(c.lower(), c) for c in plaintext)
plaintext = "hhis is a fairly long piece of plainhexh fourscore and seven" 
d = 'gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefijstuvw' #decryption key
encdic = dict(zip(alphabet, d)) #create decryption dictionary
decdic = dict(zip(d, alphabet)) #create decryption dictionary

def encrypt(plaintext, d):
    s=""
    return s.join(encdic.get(c.lower(), c) for c in plaintext)
```

When I shorten the code to:

```
return s.join(encdic.get(c) for c in plaintext)
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

How can I fix this?

Update:

I've changed the code to:

```
return s.join(encdic.get(c,c) for c in plaintext)
```

*seems* to work without error but why?

Comment: 1) Are you sure `c` is always lower case? 2) Are you sure that `c` is always a key in `encdic`? If not, you must use the longer form which ensures that the key is lower case and returns a default value if the key isn't found in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks - it its iterating through plaintext looking up each character and creating a ciphered msg - all of plain text is lower case for sue- why does my adjusted code work (since dictionary is zipped? ie looks like 'a:g', 's:f': etc , there for need a second parameter?

Comment: The type error means that one of the dictionary lookups fails and `.get()` returns a value of `None`. Are you sure you don't have a non-alpha character in `plaintext' such as a space?

Comment: yes there are spaces in plaintext - i tried adding a space to both alphabet string and the decryption key - still get an error, Thanks for your continued help

Comment: What output do you get if you add `print(repr(plaintext))` to the `encrypt()` function?

Comment: I get the following = bthw if i put i get(c,c) it works - why is that                                                                                                                                     return s.join(encdic.get(c) for c in plaintext)
TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: Can you add the exact value of plaintext to your question? It's gotten garbled in the comment. You should have a string with quotes around it from the print statement.

Comment: I'll add an answer that works for me. My only guess now is that alphabet is missing a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You key has `i` twice and is missing an `h`

**Data:**

```
d = 'gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefijstuvw'  # decryption key
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(sorted(list(set(d))))
print(sorted(list(d)))
```

**Results:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: thanks a bunch - found it as well by brute force (ie looking through -  had two "i"s and no "h.  Glad I found htis site -much appreciate all the help i got -wasted two much time on this - Sorry for being such a newb

Answer (score 0):

The get() method is defined as follows:

```
dict.get(key, default=None)
```

Since the given key c is returning None, this means the key c is not available.

You mentioned this works: `return s.join(encdic.get(c,c) for c in plaintext)`
The reason for this is because when 'c' is not found as a key, a default value c is returned. Assume alphabet is `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` the only time c will not be found is if it is whitepace. Therefore you this whitespace character will not be encrypted.

Previously when doing `return s.join(encdic.get(c) for c in plaintext)`, when c is whitespace, this will not be a valid key, since your keys consist of only the alphabet a-z.

Here is a working example:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
plaintext = "hhis is a fairly long piece of plainhexh fourscore and seven" 
d = 'gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefijstuvw' #decryption key
encdic = dict(zip(alphabet, d)) #create decryption dictionary
decdic = dict(zip(d, alphabet)) #create decryption dictionary

def encrypt(plaintext):
    return "".join(encdic.get(c, c) for c in plaintext)
def decrypt(encrypted_text):
    return "".join(decdic.get(c, c) for c in encrypted_text)

encrypted_text = encrypt(plaintext)
decrypted_text = decrypt(encrypted_text)
print("plaintext:", plaintext + '\n'
  "encrypted_text:", encrypted_text + '\n'
  "decrypted_text:", decrypted_text + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works for me.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' #space added to end
d = 'gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefijstuvw '        #space added to end

encdic = dict(zip(alphabet,d))
decdic = dict(zip(d,alphabet))

def encrypt(plaintext): #note, I removed d since it isn't used
    s=""
    return s.join(encdic.get(c) for c in plaintext)

def decrypt(encrypted): #note, I removed d since it isn't used
    s=""
    return s.join(encdic.get(c) for c in encrypted)
```

I'm able to get the encrypted string and the decrypted string using this code. The error could be in the definition of `alphabet` or you might be passing a string to decrypt that has the letter `h` in it, since this is missing from `d` so you can't decrypt and encrypted string if it contains the character 'h'.